# How do I cd into a directory using perl?

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying the following..
system "cd directoryfolder" 
but it fails, also I try system "exit" to leave the terminal but it fails.

Answer (score 25):

Code:

```
chdir('path/to/dir') or die "$!";
```

Perldoc:

```
   chdir EXPR
   chdir FILEHANDLE
   chdir DIRHANDLE
   chdir   Changes the working directory to EXPR, if possible. If EXPR is omitted,
           changes to the directory specified by $ENV{HOME}, if set; if not, changes to
           the directory specified by $ENV{LOGDIR}. (Under VMS, the variable
           $ENV{SYS$LOGIN} is also checked, and used if it is set.) If neither is set,
           "chdir" does nothing. It returns true upon success, false otherwise. See the
           example under "die".

           On systems that support fchdir, you might pass a file handle or directory
           handle as argument.  On systems that don't support fchdir, passing handles
           produces a fatal error at run time.
```

Comment: I entered the line 'chdir('folder01') or die "$!";' after my unzip line but I get the following error.
syntax error at it.pl line 6, near "system"
Execution of it.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @sirplzmywebsitelol Your "unzip line" does not make sense in this context.  Can you update your question with a more or less complete code snippet, so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: system "wget http://download.com/download.zip"
system "unzip download.zip"
chdir('download') or die "$!";
system "sh install.sh";

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the `system`, before the `chdir`.

Comment: By the way, a perl script consisting almost entirely of `system` calls should probably be a shell script instead.  Try the following directly on your command line: `wget download.com/download.zip; unzip download.zip; cd download; sh install.sh`.

Comment: Perl's [Archive::Extract](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Archive-Extract) can help you unarchive things directly from your program with the system calls.

Answer (score 14):

The reason you can't do those things by calling `system` is that `system` will start a new process, execute your command, and return the exit status.  So when you call `system "cd foo"` you will start a shell process, which will switch to the "foo" directory and then exit.  Nothing of any consequence will happen in your perl script.  Likewise, `system "exit"` will start a new process and immediately exit it again.

What you want for the cd case, is - as bobah points out - the function `chdir`.  For exiting your program, there is a function `exit`.

However - neither of those will affect the state of the terminal session you are in.  After your perl script finishes, the working directory of your terminal will be the same as before you started, and you will not be able to exit the terminal session by calling `exit` in your perl script.

This is because your perl script is again a separate process from your terminal shell, and things that happen in separate processes generally do not interfere with each other.  This is a feature, not a bug.

If you want things to change in your shell environment, you must issue instructions that are understood and interpreted by your shell.  `cd` is such a builtin command in your shell, as is `exit`.

Answer (score 5):

I always like mention [`File::chdir`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3achdir) for `cd`-ing. It allows changes to the working directory which are local to the enclosing block.

As Peder mentions, your script is basically all system calls tied together with Perl. I present a more Perl implementation.

```
"wget download.com/download.zip"; 
system "unzip download.zip" 
chdir('download') or die "$!"; 
system "sh install.sh";
```

becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple; #provides getstore
use File::chdir; #provides $CWD variable for manipulating working directory
use Archive::Extract;

#download
my $rc = getstore('download.com/download.zip', 'download.zip');
die "Download error $rc" if ( is_error($rc) );

#create archive object and extract it
my $archive = Archive::Extract->new( archive => 'download.zip' );
$archive->extract() or die "Cannot extract file";

{
  #chdir into download directory
  #this action is local to the block (i.e. {})
  local $CWD = 'download';
  system "sh install.sh";
  die "Install error $!" if ($?);
}

#back to original working directory here
```

This uses two non-core modules (and `Archive::Extract` has only been core since Perl v5.9.5) so you may have to install them. Use the `cpan` utility (or `ppm` on AS-Perl) to do this.